# Optimize paste loop

Tags: bash, unix, optimization, for-loop

I have 1000 files in `/myfolder`, each file is ~8Mb, and has 500K rows and 2 columns as below:

```
file1.txt
Col1 Col2
a 0.1
b 0.3
c 0.2
...

file2.txt
Col1 Col2
a 0.8
b 0.9
c 0.4
...
```

I need to remove 1st column - `Col1` from all the files and paste all files side by side, order of files doesn't matter.

I have following code running, it has been running for 4 hours... Anyway to speed it up?

```
for i in /myfolder/*; do \
paste all.txt <(cut -f2 ${i}) > temp.txt; \
mv temp.txt all.txt; \
done
```

Expected output:

```
all.txt
Col2 Col2 ...
0.1 0.8 ... 
0.3 0.9 ...
0.2 0.4 ...
... ... ...
```

Comment: is the first column same for all the files?

Comment: Yes, it is same for all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this task would be much easier if you would iterate over the files in parallel. For each line of each file, you just cut off the first part and then print the concatenation of the results.

In Python, that'd be something like

```
import glob

# Open all *.txt files in parallel
files = [open(fn, 'r') for fn in glob.glob('*.txt')]
while True:
    # Try reading one line from each file, collecting into 'allLines'
    try:
        allLines = [next(f).strip() for f in files]
    except StopIteration:
        break

    # Chop off everything up to (including) the first space for each line
    secondColumns = (l[l.find(' ') + 1:] for l in allLines)

    # Print the columns, interspersing space characters
    print ' '.join(secondColumns)
```

<sub><sup>Alas, making `allLines` a generator didn't seem to work - the `next` call wouldn't raise a `StopIteration` error for some reason.</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

I will not answer completely. But probably if you try this you might succed.
for example:- Merging 4 files based upon the first column:

```
join -1 1 -2 1 temp1 temp2 | join - temp3|join - temp4
```

So, you can either write a script to frame the command initially with all the files and finally execute the command.
Hope this is useful.

Comment: Are we suggesting that `join` is more efficient than `paste`? Besides,  files are not sorted.